# What does the "S" suffix for RAM modules mean?

Tags: memory, ddr

While looking for a RAM upgrade, I found two offers which apparently only differ in the "S" suffix of the type, and in the price:

- "32 GB RAM, 1 Modul, DDR4, 3200 MHz (PC4-25600), SO-DIMM 260 Pin, CL22" (~78 €), at https://archive.li/LX3gc
- "32 GB RAM, 1 Modul, DDR4, 3200 MHz (PC4-25600S), SO-DIMM 260 Pin, CL22" (~88 €), at https://archive.li/Chm5B

Both are from the same manufacturer (Kingston).

What does the "S" in "PC4-25600S" indicate? What is the actual difference between those two offers? And can I use either of these modules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RAM Part Numbers - Meaning?](https://superuser.com/questions/802453/ram-part-numbers-meaning)

Comment: @spikey_richie No, I did not find any explanation for the "S" in that linked question or in its answers (or maybe I overlooked that explanation).

Comment: It could be some manufacturer saying it is a "SODIMM" module, or that it is "Single rank". The manufacturer or supplier should know for sure.

Comment: I found some examples of the S being included on dual-rank modules, but never on desktop DIMMs, so I'm pretty sure the S means the laptop "SODIMM" size specifically. Maybe just for easier searching?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale both modules OP listed say they are SO-DIMM, and only one has the "S" in the part number. So that is not the case here.

Comment: Those are not part numbers. Perhaps speed indicators? Kingston has a RAM part number explainer site, and they do use "S" in the actual part number to denote a SO-DIMM but the number you are looking at is not a part number.

Comment: Eh I kinda take that back. Affording to a DDR spec explainer site the S following the DDR speed code does mean it is a SO-DIMM. This means the information you are looking at is incorrect or inconsistent. Whatever source of information you are looking at where you got the text you quoted is not being correct or consistent.

Comment: @music2myear Huh, interesting. I added archived links to the two offers, in case you want to look at the info yourself.